# Adjusted Bar chart label rotation

Tags: plotting, charts, rotation

I'm currently working on a bar chart diagram, where the vertical axis starts from 0.9. I managed to adjust the labels, but I don't know how to rotate it to make it readable.

The code is the following:

```
selectName = {"Downhill Simplex", "Downhill Simplex step 1 weight 10",
    "Downhill Simplex step 2 weight 10", 
   "Downhill Simplex step 3 weight 10", "Hooke Jeves", 
   "Hooke Jeeves step 1 weight 10", "Hooke Jeeves step 2 weight 10", 
   "Hooke Jeeves step 1 weight 10", "ASA"};
selectR2 = {0.999188735078198`, 0.999532701011065`, 
   0.998304716112723`, 0.992933005217847`, 0.999151413601683`, 
   0.999383404177847`, 0.99912182243453`, 0.996900703923443`, 
   0.99927713576775`};
ch = BarChart[selectR2, BarSpacing -> Large, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.9, 1}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   ChartLabels -> selectName];
labels = Cases[ch[[1]], 
  Text[lbl_, Offset[_, {pos_, _}], ___] :> {pos, lbl, 0}, -4]
Show[ch, Ticks -> {labels, Automatic}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Subtract .9 from input data and adjust the tick labels for the vertical axis to run from .9 to 1, and (2) Use the third argument of `Placed` to rotate the chart labels in `ChartLabels` settings:

```
BarChart[selectR2 - .9, BarSpacing -> Large, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[selectName, Below, Rotate[#, 80 Degree] &], 
  Ticks -> {None, Charting`FindTicks[{0, .1}, {.9, 1}]}]
```

[image]